# How to drop row in Dataframe if column is NaN and there is another row where the column is not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a pandas dataframe in python where the rows are identified by `p1` & `p2`, but `p2` is sometimes `NaN`:

```
   p1 p2
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  a  3
3  b  NaN
4  c  4
5  d  NaN
6  d  5
```

The above dataframe was returned from a larger one with many duplicates by using

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["p1","p2"], keep='last')
```

which works for the most part, the only issue being that `NaN` and `5` are technically not duplicates and therefore not dropped.

How can I drop the rows (such as: `"d", NaN`) where there is another row with the same `p1` **and** a `p2` value of `not.null` eg. `"d", 5`. The important thing here being that `"b", NaN` is kept because there are **no** rows with `"b", not.null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `groupby` and `ffill` and `bfill`, then `drop_duplicates`

```
df.assign(p2=df.groupby('p1')['p2'].apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())).\
      drop_duplicates(subset=["p1","p2"], keep='last')
Out[645]: 
  p1   p2
0  a  1.0
1  a  2.0
2  a  3.0
3  b  NaN
4  c  4.0
6  d  5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This set of duplicates should essentially be the intersection of all rows which contain `NaN` values and rows which contain duplicate `p1` elements, unioned with the those which are duplicates across both columns:

```
dupe_1 = df['p1'].duplicated(keep=False) & df['p2'].isnull()
dupe_2 = df.duplicated(subset=['p1','p2'])
total_dupes = dupe_1 | dupe_2
new_df = df[~total_dupes]
```

Note that this will fail for a dataframe such as:

```
  p1  p2
0  a NaN
1  a NaN
```

As both of those elements would be removed. Thus, we must first run `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['p1','p2'], inplace=True, keep='last')`, removing all but one of those rows, making the solution work fine once again.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=["p1","p2"], keep='last')` This should remove all of those cases, so as long as I do your answer afterward it would work

Comment: Ah, excellent point, that would definitely fix that problem. I'll edit my answer to include that.